# Can a ARB program(shader pair) use non ARB buffer objects and vertex arrays?

Tags: opengl, object, buffer, vertex, opengl-3

Can a ARB program(shader pair) use non ARB buffer objects and vertex arrays? Non ARB means with no extension, like NV, ATI, ARB, EXT or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. Note that core functionality without the ARB suffix, actually *are* the ARB extensions, made part of the regular specification. In general there's interoperability between extensions. Also each extension clearly has to state how it interacts with the rest of OpenGL and all other extensions (in existance at the time of specification).

Comment: Note that they are not always the same things. Many ARB extensions are not ported directly into the core versions. That's why it's best to just use the core stuff unless there's a specific reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Useful detail. Also makes the problem much harder :) I'm trying to implement a shadow map, and the original program uses ARB shaders, my rest of the program does'nt; Now I don't know if I must convert my existing shaders to ARB to be able the render the shadow. I can test both ways, and see if non ARB shader can render shadow.